# How to change the Python launch args on the built in VS Code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to change the launch args for the built in Python terminal in VS Code as it keeps running the code (when I press the play button the in the top right) with the wrong args.
Basically I want it so that the built in terminal will run my Python code differently (`python3 -u...` instead of `python -u`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Python extension:

## To add arguments to the python interpreter

Open settings, and search for `Python › Terminal: Launch Args`.

## To change the current Python interpreter

Try `Python: select interpreter` in the command palette.

### To change the default one

Open settings, and search for `Python: Default Interpreter Path`.

## When using the debugger

You might want to add some parameters in the `.vscode/launch.json` file. [More info about that in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).